# Credentials for Db2 in IBM

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud, access-token, credentials

I recently signed up for the Lite version (free) of Db2 in IBM. When I select 'open console', I receive an error message: {"trace":"89cc4337d11c197f1e4c12c51f027b77","errors":[{"code":"authentication_failure","message":"HWCSEC0016E: Authentication failed for SSO. This may caused by failed to generate access token in console side using existing credentials.","target":{"type":"","name":""},"more_info":""}]}.  I've placed a couple of ticktets with IBM, but they say since I signed up for the 'free' service that they are unable to assist even though I only need assistance to access the service.  Any thoughts?

Comment: My recommendation: If you have not used that free database yet, delete it and recreate. If you are using it, have you created credentials in the service dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

Deleted the existing DB instance and created a new one in different location. And that worked for me.