# While using IBM db2 open console I am getting an error

Tags: db2

```
{
  "trace": "5aff5d986c386d46d7912428cbef3543",
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": "authentication_failure",
      "message": "HWCSEC0016E: Authentication failed for SSO. This may caused by failed to generate access token in console side using existing credentials.",
      "target": {
        "type": "",
        "name": ""
      },
      "more_info": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This is not a question for stackoverflow. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62270299/credentials-for-db2-in-ibm

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be addressed to vendor support.